# Using Azure as a backup drive only

Tags: backup, cloud-storage, azure

I have some Azure credits from my MSDN subscription, but I don't need a website on there.

However I **do** have a need for backing up 300GB of photos and files to the cloud, for which I am considering using Google Drive or Dropbox.

Would be possible to set up Windows Azure just for backing up files, without a website attached?

Comment: @demoncodemonkey - How about you just look.  The `Microsoft Azure` prices are on the `Microsoft Azure` website.

Comment: @Ramhound you're right, I reworded the question to take out the pricing and other opinion-based queries. The main point here is that I don't know whether it can be used as a cloud storage drive in the same way as Dropbox can.

Comment: You can in theory. You will just pay for data uploaded and data downloaded, and the storage space. Amazon's S3 data buckets are often used by applications to serve data there is little to no different in how dropbox works in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better of with Dropbox, Google Drive or OneDrive.

Azure offers storage services, but it's meant for **applications**, not end-users. So there is no pretty interface for navigating what you store there, just an API. There are third-party apps that provide this navigation but, as you're dealing with personal data and not application data, I recommend a "standard" cloud storage.

Answer (score 1):

Azure is pretty a pretty broad system, with many services.

For example, you could use Azure to start/host a Windows 2012 Server VM, and then backup to it via many "usual" methods.